# Cats get value from the monad stack

Tags: scala, monads, monad-transformers, scala-cats

I have a monad stack for responses from my components implemented with the cats monads transformers:

```
type FutureEither[A] = EitherT[Future, Error, A] 
type FutureEitherOption[A] = OptionT[FutureEither, A]
```

the result is effectively:

```
Future[Either[Error, Option[A]]]
```

How can I get a value or error from this stack in a proper way? How can I combine the results from several calls execute in parallel in a proper way? For example in such scenario:

```
def fooServiceCall: FutureEitherOption[Foo]
def barServiceCall(f: Option[Foo]): FutureEitherOption[Bar]

for {
  r1 <- fooServiceCall
  r2 <- barServiceCall(r1)
} yield r2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second method `barServiceCall` tells in its signature that it can deal with `Option[Foo]` directly, instead of relying on the monad transformer stack to fail with `None` at some point. Therefore, you have to unpack one layer of `OptionT[EitherT[Future, Error, ?], A]`, and instead deal with `EitherT[Future, Error, Option[A]]` directly: even though your methods seem to return results in the former monad stack, the right tool in this for-comprehension is the latter one.

Recall that if `o: OptionT[F, A]`, then the wrapped `o.value` is of type `F[Option[A]]`.

Therefore, if you simply call `.value` on a `OptionT[EitherT[Future, Error, ?], A]`, you get the required `EitherT[Future, Error, Option[A]]`. Here is how it works out in code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.Either
import cats.instances.future._
import cats.instances.either._
import cats.instances.option._
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.data.OptionT
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

type Error = String        // or whatever...
type Foo = (Int, Int)      // whatever...
type Bar = (String, Float) // whatever... 

type FutureEither[A] = EitherT[Future, Error, A]
type FutureEitherOption[A] = OptionT[FutureEither, A]

def fooServiceCall: FutureEitherOption[Foo] = ???
def barServiceCall(f: Option[Foo]): FutureEitherOption[Bar] = ???


val resFut: Future[Either[Error, Option[Bar]]] = (for {
  r1 <- fooServiceCall.value // : EitherT[Future, Error, Option[Foo]]
  r2 <- barServiceCall(r1).value // : EitherT[Future, Error, Option[Bar]]
} yield r2).value

val res: Either[Error, Option[Bar]] = Await.result(resFut, 10.seconds)
```

Now the result is simple enough that you can deal with it direcly.

Alternatively, if you don't want to unpack the result here and now, you can wrap it again into an `OptionT` and keep working with a `FutureEitherOption[Bar]`:

```
val res2: FutureEitherOption[Bar] = 
  OptionT(for {
    r1 <- fooServiceCall.value
    r2 <- barServiceCall(r1).value
  } yield r2)
```

Comment: thanks, looks good. could you clarify one thing? if `fooServiceCall.value` will return `None`, will next call be `barServiceCall(None)`? I stuck with it for now... I am thinking that `Option[T]` maybe is not a good choice. From one side it is ok, because non value is not an error, but from the other side, `bar` service should take care of it, which does not look good for me.

Comment: As I've attempted to sketch out in my answer, it seems as if you're are essentially working in `EitherT[Error, Future, ?]`. At one point of the program, `?` happens to be `Option[Foo]`, but since `barServiceCall` can cope with `None` in a meaningful way, you do not fail, and instead pass the `None` to the `barServiceCall`. Thus, the mode of failure modeled by `OptionT` seems not to be necessary: you can recover from `None` and continue computation. Thus, maybe the `OptionT` is not really needed here, because it only gets in the way (at least for these two methods).

Comment: @theodor I could add a version with slightly differently chosen type constructors instead of `FutureEitherOption`. But it would  become more "code-review" style then... I think you already have the right intuition about `OptionT` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `.value` on a `OptionT[F, A]` to get a `F[Option[A]]`. And just do `OptionT()` to do the reverse. I believe `EitherT` has similar methods that you can use to wrap and unwrap these classes when you need access to internal `Option`s or `Either`s. For example, I think you could do something like:

```
val x: FutureEither[Option[Bar]] = for {
  r1 <- fooServiceCall.value
  r2 <- barServiceCall(r1).value
} yield r2
val result: FutureEitherOption[Bar] = OptionT(x)
```